# How to override methods of a third part library class?

Tags: android, mapquest

I'm using [MapQuest](http://www.mapquest.com/) for an app that contains a map. However, MapQuest lacks a few things so I wanted to improve it myself overriding some of the methods of the library.

Is there a way to do that?

I promptly thought of just creating my own MyMap and extending it from mapquest.MapView and reimplement the methods I want. However, in my XML I have this mapquest.MapView View, which I cannot just change to MyMap.

It seems either I'm missing something fundamental or it is not actually possible.

Any help?

Comment: Why can't you just change it to MyMap?

Comment: It throws an error when Android tries to inflate it.

Comment: What error is shown? Could you please provide more information and code? It's nearly impossible ti help you, if it's not clear what the problem exactly is.

Comment: That's awkward, but I re-wrote my code and I think I was just forgetting to specify the whole package name of my custom class. It worked now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This should only be done as a last resort, but you could copy the source code of the class you want to change and create a copy of it with exactly the same package declaration and classname. You also need to make sure that the classloader takes preference to your custom class. I think there is a good chance that Android Studio will take care of this for you.

What should happen is: the library class gets loaded first, but then your class overrides it.

Comment: I can't see the source code because they are compiled already. See image: http://www.resizemyimage.net/images/c094d956-078c-4195-a79a-1bc249e1fbe1/Screenshot%20from%202015-03-09%2015:38:15.png

Comment: Maybe you can use a decompiler? https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Decompiling_Java_bytecode

Answer (score 0):

In my specific case, I found it is possible to do this:

```
MapView map;
...
map.addMapViewEventListener(new MapView.MapViewEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void moveStart(MapView mapView) {
        // do something
    }
...
```

However these methods are not enough for me, and this does not actually answer my question.